# How to generate rounded polygon for my buttons' background

Tags: css, svg, background

I am currently looking on how to create such background for my buttons in my website.[image: Button background]

I thought the best way was to use SVG, but I am struggling to generate a nice SVG that do not scale as the example in the image. I would like to keep the arc circle on left and right and just expand the top and bottom border when I need to resize.

I am really a newbie in SVG and code. My are of expertise is Design.

Here you have the SVG code

```
<svg width="105" height="48" viewBox="0 0 105 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Does anyone has an idea on how I can manage this design?

Comment: SVG filters seem to be an option https://dev.to/afif/css-shapes-with-rounded-corners-56h

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think it's like this: you need to put it inside the `<button>` tag something like this

```html
    <button>
        <svg width="105" height="48" viewBox="0 0 105 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> </svg>
    </button>
```

So what's happening right now is when you put `svg` inside the button html will include the content in the button.